# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:12.0.1

Tags: android, cordova, admob, cordova-admob

I am using Visual Studio Apache Cordova and in there I am having an admob service. I updated my google play services as well as google support services via sdk. Besides, I updated everything from my android sdk, but I am still seeing this error.
I do see something on google post that these services are no longer supported via sdk but need to be put as dependencies in the project itself. But I don't know how to proceed with that

Answer (score 3):

Solution here:
[Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794020/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-basement12-0-1)

In next future, I recommend to update gradle and SDK in your project.

For now you can to try to add maven in android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript { 
 repositories { 
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    jcenter()
    ...
 ...
 allprojects { 
   repositories { 
     mavenLocal() 
     maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
     jcenter()
     ...
 ...
```

Comment: It seems to have solved my initial issue. Thanks a lot for that. The only issue I have now is it is not deploying it on my device connected. I have to copy the build to my phone to test it.