# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1

Tags: android, react-native, admob

Here is my dependencies

```
dependencies {

        compile project(':react-native-fcm')
        // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0' //FCM - this decides your firebase SDK version
        compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
        }
        compile(project(":react-native-google-place-picker")){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        compile (project(':RNAdMob')){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        //compile project(':react-native-device-info')
        compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        compile (project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        compile project(':react-native-android-location-enabler')
        compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
        compile project(':react-native-sound')

        compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
        compile (project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        //compile project(':react-native-device-info')
        compile(project(":react-native-device-info")){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
        //compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.44.3"

        compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        compile (project(':tipsi-stripe')){
            exclude group: "com.google.firebase"
            exclude group: "com.android.support"
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2' // should be at least 9.0.0
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'

    }
```

Error getting from RNAdMob project. but i have excluded the gms package. I didnt do any changes in the code. Yesterday its worked and compiled. I`m wonder why today its not compiling. Im not added "play-services-basement:12.0.1" module anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **android/app/build.gradle** add this:

```
def _ext = rootProject.ext
def _googlePlayServicesVersion = _ext.has('googlePlayServicesVersion') ? _ext.googlePlayServicesVersion : '+'
```

In **android/build.gradle** add this:

```
ext { 
    // dependency versions
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"     
}
```

In general, In next future I recomend to update gradle and SDK in your project

For now you can to try to add maven in **android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript { 
 repositories { 
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    jcenter()
    ...
 ...
 allprojects { 
   repositories { 
     mavenLocal() 
     maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
     jcenter()
     ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 26):

Move `google()` to before `jcenter()` in your build.gradle e.g.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it for me -- does anyone know why OP's error occurs?