# React Native build fails after add firebase setup

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I need to set up my react-native app with firebase and I followed the firebase setup guide and after that rerun the app but it fails with giving me errors, I tried lots of solutions that available on the internet but still my issue is not fixed.

if anyone have got this issue before and fixed it already, could you please help me to fix this issue.

this is the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:12.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.aar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.aar
       - https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-12.0.1.aar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:12.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.aar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.aar
       - https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-api-12.0.1.aar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:12.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.aar
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/iswan/works/office/xforce/xForceMobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.aar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.aar
       - https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk/12.0.1/play-services-measurement-sdk-12.0.1.aar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }


        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794020/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-basement12-0-1

Comment: @GauravRoy no not working for me

Comment: show your build.gradle

Comment: @AjithMadhu add my build.gradle too

Comment: not this bro .. one inside app/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AjithMadhu I found the issue, it because of the below section. I hardcoded before a month ago and I didn't notice that one.

```
subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: :-) happy to help. bro

Answer (score 0):

well this is how I done. please refer this,

android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
    + classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // check this line

}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
+ implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
+ implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
+ implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
}
```

android/
grade.properties

```
firebaseCoreVersion=17.2.1
firebaseMessagingVersion=20.0.1
```

MainApplication.java

```
+ import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
+ import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;

 @Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  packages.add(new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage());
  packages.add(new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage());      
  return packages;
}
```